# How does Spring do injection when the autowired property has a unassigned final int?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok

I was reading the source code of a project, but I ran into this problem.

The class A be like:

```
@Component
class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initA () {
        C c = new(1);
        b.setC(c);
    }
}
```

The Class B be like:

```
@Component
class B {
    @Setter
    private C c;
}
```

The Class C be like:

```
@Data
class C {
    private final int i;
}
```

I am so confused. I thought the @PostConstruct Method works after Spring injection. So what is the value of c.i before @PostConstruct? How does this injection work well?

Comment: C isn't Spring managed, so that question doesn't really apply as there is no instance before `@PostConstruct` is being called.